# creating new view while running in relative layout (middle of the layout)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have an XML file like this and I want with pressing the "+" button, the user shall be able to add more names, addresses, etc to the form. [like most web forms on Internet that have "Add more" button]

In java code, I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583019/dynamic-textview-in-relative-layout) codes for creating new textview while running, but my problem is that all samples that I found is for an empty relative layout.
So I'm trying to create a new textview in middle of layout and I need the views after new view to shift down.

If I want to change every single view, my code will be so long, and it's not appropriate, I think.

How can I do this? This is my relative layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by having a layout like so:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/root">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/name_container">
      <Button android:id="@+id/add_name" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/address_container">
      <Button android:id="@+id/add_address"
  </LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, each  of these "containers" will contain `EditText` of respective type. For example, `name_container` will contain `EditText` for names, and so on.

Whenever a user clicks on a particular button, just inflate a view of the appropriate type and add it to the corresponding container. If you want to animate the addition / removal of views, use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

This way, you are adding views "in the middle" of the layout. Android will handle the animation and redrawing for you without having to write any code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a beginner in Android. I didn't work with inflating views, Could you write a sample code for me please? Thank you

Comment: There's a lot of tutorials and documentation out there. It shouldnt be a problem finding something useful.

Comment: ow, sorry, I found it. I forgot to delete my comment. Thank you